# Anchoring SKAnnotation by customView at runtime

Tags: android, skmaps

Running SDK 2.5.1, I'm trying to add my own SKAnnotations with my customView, whose size changes dynamically depending on the name displayed. To do this, I've attached an OnGlobalLayoutListener, to set the annotation's offset accordingly. However, it seems the global listener is not being called at all. I've tried attaching the it to both mapView.getAnnotationView().getView(), to mapView and to the mapHolder of the fragment, with no results. Any solution to allow me to anchor my annotations to the actual location would be appreciated.

```
final SKAnnotation newDelhi = new SKAnnotation(444);
    newDelhi.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    newDelhi.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
    SKAnnotationView newDelhiAnnotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
    RelativeLayout newDelhiCustomView =
            (RelativeLayout) ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                    R.layout.annotation_layout, null, false);
    newDelhiCustomView.setTag("new delhi");
    newDelhiAnnotationView.setView(newDelhiCustomView);
    newDelhi.setAnnotationView(newDelhiAnnotationView);
    TextView newDelhiTextView = (TextView) newDelhiAnnotationView.getView().findViewById(R.id.annotation_textview);
    newDelhiTextView.setText("New Delhi");
    SKCoordinate newDelhiLocation = new SKCoordinate(77.179163, 28.619828);
    newDelhi.setLocation(newDelhiLocation);
    addRedPin(newDelhiLocation, 445);
    mapView.addAnnotation(newDelhi, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mapHolder.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mapHolder.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            float width = newDelhi.getAnnotationView().getView().getWidth();
            float height = newDelhi.getAnnotationView().getView().getHeight();
            newDelhi.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint(-width / 2, height / 2));
            mapView.updateAnnotation(newDelhi);
        }
    });

    final SKAnnotation chandigarh = new SKAnnotation(555);
    chandigarh.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    chandigarh.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
    SKAnnotationView chandigahrAnnotationView= new SKAnnotationView();
    RelativeLayout chandigarhCustomView =
            new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    chandigarhCustomView.setTag("chandigarh");
    TextView chandigarhTextView = new TextView(getActivity());
    chandigarhTextView.setText("Chandigarh");
    chandigarhCustomView.addView(chandigarhTextView);
    chandigahrAnnotationView.setView(chandigarhCustomView);
    chandigarh.setAnnotationView(chandigahrAnnotationView);
    SKCoordinate chandigarhLocation = new SKCoordinate(76.778867,30.736094);
    chandigarh.setLocation(chandigarhLocation);
    mapView.addAnnotation(chandigarh, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {                mapHolder.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            float width = chandigarh.getAnnotationView().getView().getWidth();
            float height = chandigarh.getAnnotationView().getView().getHeight();
            chandigarh.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint(-width / 2, height / 2));
            mapView.updateAnnotation(newDelhi);
        }
    });

    addRedPin(chandigarhLocation, 556);
```

Here is a screenshot of how the annotations wrongly appear (actual locations are red pins):
[image]

Comment: Question routed to Scout developers